# angular2 - no service provider for DatepickerConfig

Tags: angular, ng2-bootstrap, ng2-datepicker

I am implementing ng2-bootstrap datepicker, but getting the below error. Please help me on this.

```
EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in
         http://localhost:8888/app/components/report.component.html:3:0 caused by: No provider for DatepickerConfig!
```

**module.ts**

```
 import { DatepickerModule } from 'ng2-bootstrap';

  @NgModule({
   imports: [DatepickerModule],
   declarations: [],
   providers: [],
   bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

**component.ts**

```
@Component({
 module: module.id,
 selector:'my-date',
 template: `
  <h4>My Date Picker</h4>
  <datepicker></datepicker>`
})

 export class MyComponent {
 }
```

**systemjs.config.js**

```
System.config({ map: { 'ng2-bootstrap':
 'npm:ng2-bootstrap/bundles/ng2-bootstrap.umd.js'} })
```

Comment: Is the issue solved?

Answer (score 10):

You should use forRoot() as it is defined that way in the sample repository.

```
  @NgModule({
   imports: [DatepickerModule.forRoot()],
   declarations: [],
   providers: [],
   bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

> By convention, the forRoot static method both provides and configures services at the same time. It takes a service configuration object and returns a ModuleWithProviders which is a simple object with two properties:
>
> • ngModule - the CoreModule class
>
> • providers - the configured providers
>
> The root AppModule imports the CoreModule and adds the providers to the AppModule providers.

Source: [https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html#!#configure-core-services-with-*coremodule-forroot*](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html#!#configure-core-services-with-_coremodule-forroot_)

Sample repository: https://github.com/valor-software/angular2-quickstart/blob/master/app/app.module.ts

Comment: @arn-arn glad I could help :-)